# Airplane Closed Flight Path Enclosing Greatest Area

Tags: multivariable-calculus, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, euler-lagrange-equation

> Suppose an airplane with fixed air speed $v_{0}$ makes a flight lasting $T$ seconds. Suppose the air has velocity $0 < a < v_{0}$ in the positive $y$ direction. Find that closed curve along which the plane should fly if this curve is to enclose the greatest area.

Let the curve be denoted by $C$ and the region it bounds be denoted by $R$. We wish to maximize the functional
$$ A[C] = \iint_{R}d(x,y) .$$
Green's theorem provides a method of computing this
$$\iint_{R}d(x,y) = \int_{C}xdy = \int_{0}^{T}x(t)y'(t) \, dt .$$

Let that integrand be denoted by $F$ and the next be denoted by $G$. A constraint is that the airspeed is fixed, so $\sqrt{x'^{2}+(y'-a)^{2}} = v_{0}$ and 
$$Tv_{0} = \int_{0}^{T}\sqrt{x'^{2}+(y'-a)^{2}} \, dt$$. Put $F^{*} = F-\lambda G$ where $\lambda$ is a constant (Lagrange Multiplier) Any solutions $x$ and $y$ must satisfy
$$ \frac{d}{dt}F_{x'}^{*} = F_{x}^{*} $$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}F_{y'}^{*} = F_{y}^{*} .$$

We know that the final answer should be an ellipse but this results in a differential equation that we (nor Mathematica) can solve. So there must be an error somewhere. Either in our understanding of the question (the constraint $G$ could be wrong?) or our execution.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't worked anything out, but I have two comments. It seems to me that the constraint should be a pointwise statement, not an integral statement. And you also need the boundary condition that $x(T)=x(0)=0$ and $y(T)=y(0)=0$, say.

Comment: I agree with the boundary condition. We had it writhen down and I put it in Mathematica with no success. The constraints in our text are always integral statements so that is what I used. But it can be made a point wise statement easily: $\sqrt {x'^2 +(y'-a)^2} = v_{0} $.